# Build files from template and add tweaks (turn images into conky configs)

Tags: python, bash, shell, automation, conky

I found very good Pinterest pictures which I want to randomly show on my desktop. I already have a script(s) that randomly call [conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) configs from a directory. (Then I manually make bash scripts that call from 1 to 3+ conkies at a time)

Tried to do some python scripting but it didn't... I over complicated it. Here's the [GIT FILES](https://github.com/omarali-koy/Stack_Overflow_Questions/tree/master/conky%20(copy%201)):

I was planning to show my code but it's too big and messy.

Originally I just read all the images and their Width, Height, Path and File name to separate txt files. Like width.txt, path.txt,etc. Looked like these (These is the Path.txt):

```
/home/omarali/scripts/conky/conky-sets/images/record.jpg
/home/omarali/scripts/conky/conky-sets/images/subtle.jpg
/home/omarali/scripts/conky/conky-sets/images/trust.jpg
```

Then I had a python script to convert the data to arrays and then build files one by one. Somehow I got syntax errors and etc. I didn't include the code here since it's too long and I'm considering to start from ***scratch***.

Essentially I would make a new file that has the same name as the image then replace below config variables (WIDTH,HEIGHT,etc) with the images size and path.

The template Conky config:

```
conky.config = {

    --Various settings

    double_buffer = true,                       -- eliminates flicker   

    --Windows

    own_window = true,                          -- create your own window to draw
    own_window_argb_visual = true,              -- use ARGB 
    own_window_type = 'override',               -- keeps the image in the back 


    --Placement

    alignment = 'middle_middle',                -- position of the conky

    --#########################################################################################
    --########################      THE IMPORTANT CHANGABLE STUFF       #######################
    --#########################################################################################

    minimum_width = WIDTH,                      -- minimum height of window
    minimum_height = HEIGHT,                    -- minimum height of window
};

    conky.text = [[
    ${image PATH -s SIZE}

]];
```

- WIDTH:  width of the image
- HEIGHT: height of the image
- PATH:   path to the image
- SIZE:  width + "x" + height of the image

This is the final result of the conky config.

```
conky.config = {
    minimum_width = 800,                        -- minimum height of window
    minimum_height = 1300,                      -- minimum height of window
};

    conky.text = [[
    ${image /home/omarali/scripts/conky/conky-sets/images/record.jpg -s 800x1300}

]];
```

So, Just need a simple way to put the images into a conkies that I can later call from a bash script. Python or Bash script will do.

**Here what I'm looking for:**

1. **Build a conky config from each image in a directory. let's say *dir_pins***
2. **Each conky should have the same name as the image. (this was my issue)**
3. **Can be python or bash script, open to ideas but prefer these 2.**

That's it, as mentioned before I already have a script to auto run my configs. Really appreciate your help. And open to new ideas.

Comment: I don't know why you keep size and path in separated files. You should keep them together for "data integrity".

Comment: Python has string formating like `"image {} -s {}".format(PATH, SIZE)` or in new Python `f-string` `f"image {PATH} -s {SIZE}"` so you can create string with all text, and use `for` loop to generate many versions and save in different files.

Comment: If you think that separated files are simpler then use them. You can read both files and use `zip()` to group `path` with `size` - `for (path, size) in zip(all_pathes, all_sizes):` - and then use it with string formating.

Comment: My real issue was reading and writing the file. As you see the config file is a whole paragraph... I don't know how to make the file name same as the image name and at the same time edit every file with the images' size (width and height).

Comment: image filename is a string so use string functions to get interesting part of name and create string with new filename. And later use `open(new_name, 'w')` and `write()` to save it with new name.

Comment: you can put paragraph as text in code and put `{}` in this text in places in which you want to put values - and string formating will put values in place of `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can read data from all files

```
all_widths = open('width.txt').read().splitlines()
all_heights = open('width.txt').read().splitlines()
all_pathes = open('path.txt').read().splitlines()
```

and use `zip()` to group `width` with `path`

```
for width, height, path in zip(all_widths, all_height, all_pathes):
    print(width, height, path)
    # generate conky text
```

and then you can use text with all paragrath and put `{}` in places in which you want to put data to generate new text. Because it use `{}` to recognize places for values so it need `{{` and `}}` for normal `{`, `}`

```
template = '''conky.config = {{
    minimum_width = {WIDTH},                        -- minimum height of window
    minimum_height = {HEIGHT},                      -- minimum height of window
}};

    conky.text = [[
    ${{image {PATH} -s {WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}}}

]];'''
for width, height, path in zip(all_widths, all_height, all_pathes):
    new_text = template.format(WIDTH=width, HEIGHT=height, PATH=path)
    print(new_text)
```

Now you have to use image filename to create name for conky file (I don't know what extension it uses so I use `.txt`)

```
new_name = path.replace('.jpg', '.txt')
```

or only last part of path

```
new_name = path.split('/')[-1].replace('.jpg', '.txt')
```

and then you can save text

```
f = open(new_name, 'w')
f.write(new_text)
f.close()
```

---

Full code but not tested:

```
template = '''conky.config = {{
    minimum_width = {WIDTH},                        -- minimum height of window
    minimum_height = {HEIGHT},                      -- minimum height of window
}};

    conky.text = [[
    ${{image {PATH} -s {WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}}}

]];'''

all_widths = open('width.txt').read().splitlines()
all_heights = open('width.txt').read().splitlines()
all_pathes = open('path.txt').read().splitlines()

for width, height, path in zip(all_widths, all_height, all_pathes):
    new_text = template.format(WIDTH=width, HEIGHT=height, PATH=path)
    #new_name = path.replace('.jpg', '.txt')
    new_name = path.split('/')[-1].replace('.jpg', '.txt')
    f = open(new_name, 'w')
    f.write(new_text)
    f.close()
```

---

By the way: you could use `os.listdir()` or `os.walk()` to get pathes for images directly from disk. And module `PIL` to get sizes of images.

```
template = '''conky.config = {{
    minimum_width = {WIDTH},                        -- minimum height of window
    minimum_height = {HEIGHT},                      -- minimum height of window
}};

    conky.text = [[
    ${{image {PATH} -s {WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}}}

]];'''

from PIL import Image

directory = '/home/omarali/scripts/conky/conky-sets/images/'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

    width, height = Image.open(path).size

    new_text = template.format(WIDTH=width, HEIGHT=height, PATH=path)
    new_name = filename.replace('.jpg', '.txt')

    f = open(new_name, 'w')
    f.write(new_text)
    f.close()
```

Comment: It worked! Never knew there was a listdir and path.join for os. This really helps a lot. Thank you,